# Set a seen flag to an email inside a .pst file using Java

Tags: java, email, outlook

I'm working with [libpst](https://github.com/rjohnsondev/java-libpst) and I can manage to read an email from my 'archive.pst' file from outlook, but I can´t manage to change the flag to 'read' of that email. Thats a problem, because I keep reading the same email.
Here is a copy of the program:

```
private void processFolder (PSTFolder folder) throws PSTException, IOException {

    if( folder.getUnreadCount() > 0){
        PSTMessage email = (PSTMessage)folder.getNextChild();
        while ( email != null && email.isRead() ) {
            printDepth();
            System.out.println("Email: " + email.getSubject());
            email = (PSTMessage)folder.getNextChild();
        }
        if(email != null){
            System.out.println("Email: " + email.getSubject());
            saveAttachments(email);
                /* here is where I need to mark this particualry mail as Read */
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read/unread state is governed by the MSGFLAG_READ bit (0x1) in the PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS property (0x0E070003).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I think there is no property on the Class that I can change it. I'll need to modify the class no?

Comment: I am no familiar with the libpst library, but if you can access raw MAPI properties (look at how the getSubject method is implemented), you should be able to access 0x0E070003.

Comment: Can you recommend me a link to look how to access the raw MAPI properties? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Access the properties from the libpst library? Again, I am not familiar with it. Look at its source code to see how they access other MAPI properties, such as the subject. Its MAPI property tag is 0x0037001F (PR_SUBJECT_W) or 0x0037001E (PR_SUBJECT_A). If you want to see what other properties are available, take a look at  messages with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button) - http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/

Comment: I was asking in general, not particularly on this library. Anyway, thanks! It was very helpful, now I will keep looking.

Comment: Accessing the properties is very much API dependent - libpst would be completely different from the Extended MAPI or Outlook Object Model (native Outlook APIs).